# mysql clustring

Tags: mysql

i have to manage a large scale mysql database server to handle about 20-30mil request per hour
i read about mysql clustering but there are some difficult points that i dont understand

first i referenced this document :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04

there isa mysql manager with two node
it don't distribute what happens if manager fails?

there are some other options like table sharding or Kubernetes solutions
but i dont know what is a bet choice?!

is there a topology for mysql to handle large transaction with reliability !?

**UPDATE:**
my hardware for cluster is :
3 dedicated server each one
hp g10
dual cpu 14 core 35 mb cache
512 gig hard
6*400 gig ssd raid 10

Comment: You don't mention your hardware setup (CPU, RAM and esp. your HDD/SSD) config. Before going down the cluster route, I would see if a single machine could handle this load - I'm thinking that with a half way decent SSD RAID setup, you could handle this load with relative ease - dependent on data volumes obviously!

Comment: @Vérace thank you, i added the hardware specification but i need the cluster for better performance and reliability , but if one of them is cluster manager it has risk again!!

Comment: Let's hear about the data ingestion process -- How many threads?  Via web server?  One row at a time?  How big is the row?  Possible to batch, say, 100 rows at a time?  All data goes into one table?  Etc, etc.

Comment: "Mysql cluster" is ambiguous -- NDB?  Galera?  InnoDB Cluster?  Clustrix?  Would the nodes be physically close to each other?  What about disaster recovery if the power goes out for the cluster?

Comment: That might add up to more than 20TB per year.  Will you be purging data?  Summarizing data?  Do you need access to specific rows?

Comment: I ask all these questions because we will need to optimize each aspect, else the task is beyond the capability of affordable hardware.  For example, that disk subsystem will fill up in a week or two.  I have lots of tips, but it would be more efficient for you to narrow the requirements rather than my throwing a bucket of ideas your way.

Comment: You mentioned sharding.  What column would you shard on?  Is it OK to have 100 shards?  That means 100 machines, plus disaster-recovery backup machines.  How would you do queries across shards?  Some queries are easy; some are so messy that you need to avoid sharding.

Comment: @RickJames i try to answer all your question.this is a vehicle tracker software that must handle 30-40k car. cars send up to 2000 location data per day. its not important to use NDB? Galera? InnoDB Cluster? Clustrix? i just need to system be up and fast. servers are in a physical rack.all tables are innodb and 4-5 table have huge transaction.i can delete old data but the important thing is process real time status...

Comment: @peimanF. - "real time status" -- as in "engine on"?  It would save a huge amount of space to only save significant status _changes_.  If you need to draw a map of where the vehicles are, then I ask how long you need to keep the detailed data.  Summarized data could be the approximate location whenever it stopped moving.

Comment: @peimanF. - Some performance issued can be helped if you allow the data to be collected for, say, 5 minutes, then store only the significant info.  That is, is a 5-minute delay OK for reporting?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes 40K vehicles sending location and status information 2K times per day.

**Ingestion of data**

I strongly advise that the `PRIMARY KEY` for the main table *start* with `vehicle_id`.  That id should be a 3-byte `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`, thereby allowing up to 16M vehicles.  (Smallint's limit of 64K is cutting it too close.)

Decide what output you need, then work backward to specify the minimum amount of data to store.  Meanwhile, capture the raw incoming messages from the vehicles in plain text file, *just in case you need to look back for more details*.  (This may satisfy some legal issues.)

2000/day = 1 or 2 per minute.  At high speed, the vehicle can go more than a mile (or km) between signals.

Don't forget to worry about driving through a tunnel.

May I ask what country your are doing this in?  Some countries have lax requirements, some are quite strict, in reference for this "sensitive" data.

To allow for very efficient deletion of data, `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` and use `DROP PARTITION` instead of `DELETE`.  Details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint  With that, there will be essentially no downtime to purge 'old' data.

How much RAM?  For ingestion, my above advice needs about 1GB of the buffer_pool to keep 30-40K "hotspots" in RAM.  What other tasks are regularly performed?  Especially the main `SELECTs`.

Is the data coming as HTTP requests?  Is it 30M/hour (8K/sec) or 80M/day (1K/sec); your numbers seem inconsistent-- please check.  Either way, it would need a lot of web servers.  And there is still some issues to solve to get the ingestion speed up.

Is there any "normalization" to do?  For example, does the message identify the vehicle with a 17-character VIN?  This would need to be mapped to a 3-byte Mediumint in order to cut back significantly on the disk space.  Such is best done by collecting the info in a "staging" table, then normalizing en masse.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table  (And hence my question about the possible delay before the data is available for queries.)